# How to handle NULL values in QgsExpression()?

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, null, qgsexpression

When I try to add multiple conditions in `QgsExpression()`

eg:
`QgsExpression(f"input='{abc}' OR value='{def}'")` here `abc = 1` and `def = NULL`. Even though `abc` is having value I am getting NULL in return. How to handle this?

Here `abc` and `def` are column names.

I need to get the row based on the value of `abc` even though `def` is NULL.

Comment: Could you please provide example data and the expected output of your formula for this data?

Comment: The usual SQL operator to test for NULL is "IS" (`fieldname IS NULL`)

Comment: Yea. But IS NULL returns NULL when one of the value is NULL right? I want to get the row even if one of the condition is TRUE

Comment: Please find the below example.
def1 = 'NULL'
valExp = f"value IS NULL" if def1 == 'NULL' else f"value='{def1}'"
exp = QgsExpression(f"input='{abc}' OR {valExp}")

Sorry i need to get the row when both the conditions are TRUE. When i use AND i am getting NULL as return value instead of the row